# Десериализация данных JsonConvert

Tags: c#, json

Как можно десериализовать такую структуру?

```
{
    "dataClass": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "dateCreated": "2023-10-09T13:12:57.127122",
            "responsibleId": 1,
            "responsible": null,
            "organizationId": 1,
            "organization": null,
            "dateWelded": "2023-10-09T13:12:57.1279745",
            "section": "4106",
            "cipher": "4633/2019-ПГ4",
            "line": "SL-4564",
            "materialId": 1,
            "material": null,
            "category": "BIV",
            "percentControl": 1,
            "joinNumber": "145",
            "joinType": "C17",
            "typeWelded": 1,
            "size1": "159x8",
            "size2": "159x8",
            "welder1Id": 1,
            "welder1": null,
            "styma1": "X0H",
            "styma2": "X0H",
            "status": 0,
            "pk": 0,
            "result": 0,
            "description": "",
            "dateControl": "2023-10-09T13:12:57.1293597"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "dateCreated": "2023-10-09T13:13:02.9919962",
            "responsibleId": 1,
            "responsible": null,
            "organizationId": 2,
            "organization": null,
            "dateWelded": "2023-10-09T13:13:02.991998",
            "section": "123",
            "cipher": "1794-1014(4106)-08",
            "line": "sadas",
            "materialId": 3,
            "material": null,
            "category": "hgfdh",
            "percentControl": 0,
            "joinNumber": "25",
            "joinType": "C17",
            "typeWelded": 0,
            "size1": "234",
            "size2": "320",
            "welder1Id": 1,
            "welder1": null,
            "styma1": "",
            "styma2": "",
            "status": 0,
            "pk": 0,
            "result": 0,
            "description": "",
            "dateControl": "2023-10-09T13:13:02.9919984"
        },
    ],
    "success": true,
    "message": ""
}
```

Класс RegistryModel

```
public class RegistryModel
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string dateCreated { get; set; }
}
```

Класс MainResponseModel

```
public class MainResponseModel<T>
{
    public T? DataClass { get; set; }
    public bool Success { get; set; } = true;
    public string Message { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

Мой код десериализации который не работает:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    string url = $"{_baseUrl}/api/Registry/GetAll";
    var apiResponse = await client.GetAsync(url);

    if (apiResponse.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        var response = await apiResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var deserializeResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MainResponseModel<RegistryModel>>(response);

        if (deserializeResponse.Success)
        {
            returnResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RegistryModel>>(deserializeResponse.DataClass.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Этот код вываливает исключение:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'WeldedSystem.Mobile.Models.RegistryModel' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.

Я что-то не понял?

Comment: На какую из строк десереализации то ругается? И я не уверен, что этот трюк с `ToString` пройдёт. Мне кажется вам нужно сразу нормально описать классы для сериализации, сразу уже со списком внутри.

Comment: `DeserializeObject<MainResponseModel<RegistryModel[]>>` - читайте текст ошибки

Comment: Начните с изучения спецификации [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html). Почему большинство этого не делают?